# Local Git repo is still working even though .git file is deleted

Tags: git, git-bash

I have accidentally initialized a local repo on a desktop so I have deleted .git file but even though I delete it is still acting as a repo. git commands are still working and when I do git init is says initialized repo, but when git commands are already working and if I use git init it should show as re-initialized.

Could someone please help with what's causing this issue?

Comment: Removing the `.git` directory (it's normally *not* a file, although there are special cases where it is a file, in which case this is all a bit different) removes the *repository itself*. That won't affect any *other* repositories, but running `git init` will then create a *new* repository, not re-initialize the existing one. Everything else you've described could be entirely normal since you have not been very specific. It's like saying that you walked out of a room but were still in a building: people would just say "and so what?"

Comment: you got it all wrong.... I have deleted .git file but I was able to use all git commands when It shouldn't work

Comment: And so what? Perhaps you were still in a Git repository, just not the one you deleted. You must be *specific*. *Show* what you did (cut and paste). *Show* what you expected to happen and what happened instead. Provide a reproducer if possible. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You may have another `.git` folder in some other parent directory.

Run : [`git rev-parse --git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---git-dir) from a place where you would expect git commands to not work.